# Как исправить многомерный массив чтоб он был без границ?

Tags: java, массивы, eclipse

```
public class FileReaderUpdate {

    static String m [][] = new String [2][3];
    static Scanner sc;

    public static void main (String [] argv) {

        openfile();
        readfile();
        out();
    }
}
......
```

Как исправить "`static String m [][] = new String [2][3];`"
чтоб он был без границ, чтоб сам вычислял сколько строк и какова длина строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте `ArrayList`

```java
List<List<String>> mainList;

mainList = new ArrayList<>;

List sublist = new ArrayList<>;
sublist.add("Привет");

mainList.add(sublist);
```

получить размер массива `mainList.size()`

Comment: У меня есть текстовый файл, мне надо вывести это все через массив в консоль.

Comment: 1. без массива выводить нельзя? можно было символами это сделать 2. если массив, тогда только примитивный тип можно использовать? Так как `List` тоже работает как массив